# How to run a jupyter notebook through a remote server on local machine?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, remote-access, remote-server

I have a remote access to remote server from my university and I'm accessing it through my local machine! However, my local machine has not enough memory to run multiple jupyter notebooks. Is there any way to run them through the remote server, which probably speed up tasks!! I'm not quite sure though!

I access the server from the terminal in macOS.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There's quite a good tutorial [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/remote-jupyter-notebook/)

Essentially you just run the notebook on the remote in no browser mode.

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080
```

Then setup up an ssh tunnel from the local machine:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 <REMOTE_USER>@<REMOTE_HOST>
```

Then in your local browser go to: http://localhost:8080/

###### EDIT:

Running on a specific port is not necessary. The `--no-browser` tag is.

Comment: This http://localhost:8080/ does not open for me.

Comment: I'll add a few links with some references therein since the two answers so far seem to be making good suggestions; however, sometimes it is easier with a little more explanation available and a sense of what parts can be varied. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/running-notebooks-remotely/6616/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebook-do-not-open-after-connecting-to-an-ec2-instance/3018/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/issue-in-terminal-with-redirecting-to-jupyter-notebook/8120/10?u=fomightez).

Comment: It would be useful to mention that the second step is on the local machine, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had a follow-up question. This Jupyter notebook running on the remote server, will it have access to my local virtual environments? Or will it need a virtual environment of its own on the remote server?

Comment: The only connection you have to the notebook is via your browser via the tunnel you set up on port 8080, so yeah you'd need to be managing your environments on the remote machine too.

Answer (score 16):

I think you might be looking for port-forwarding.

e.g. when you're logged into your remote via ssh you can:

1. On the remote machine, start jupyter notebook from your current directory and specify the port:

   ```
   jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=9999
   ```
2. On the local machine, catch the forwarded port:

   ```
   ssh -NfL localhost:9999:localhost:9999 your_user_name@remote_ip_address
   ```
3. Go to `http://localhost:9999`. You should be able to select your notebook and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 10):

you can run `jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip="<remote server ip>"` on your remote machine terminal. And access notebooks using http://:8888/?token=<> from your browser on local machine.

Comment: This was just what I needed to run the haskell kernel on windows 10 with jupyter notebook running in wsl

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume that the local user `localuser` and host as `localhost`, the remote user and remote host as `remoteuser` and `remotehost`. To run a Jupyter notebook on remote server from your local machine you can follow the steps below.

1. On remote machine run Jupyter notebook with `--no-browser` with specifying a port

   ```
   jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=XXXX
   ```
2. Forward it to your local machine via SSH

   ```
   ssh -N -f -L localhost:YYYY:localhost:XXXX remoteuser@remotehost
   ```
3. Open a browser and go to `http://localhost:YYYY`

You may need to close the connection

- Stop your running notebook with `CTRL+C` then `y`
- Kill the process running on port `YYYY`, `netstat` returns you the process ID (PID)

  ```
   sudo netstat -lpn | grep :YYYY -> for LINUX
   sudo netstat -anv | grep YYYY -> for MacOS

   kill PROCESS_ID
  ```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between ports YYYY vs XXXX?

Answer (score 6):

To access the remote machine with a browser the notebook must listen on an external facing port (not localhost). You will need the same invocation if want to run the Jupyter notebook on a container. In that case it is something like this:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

To listen only in localhost then you can omit the IP

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080
```

To access remotely the ssh tunnel option in other answers works. You will need an SSH tunnel per notebook. If you need to run multiple notebooks, another option is using the [`sshuttle`](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) tool to simulate a VPN over SSH so you don't have to create multiple tunnels. Run `sshuttle` with the option to have full reachability to the network of your remote machine (e.g. 10.250.100.40/24) or you can run it to forward all the traffic through the remote machine (like a traditional VPN).

```
# forward all traffic to network of remote server over the SSH VPN
sshuttle --dns -NHr username@sshserver 10.250.100.40/24

# forward all traffic through the remote server over the SSH VPN
sshuttle --dns -NHr username@sshserver 0/0
```

Note: The DNS flag is important to be able to use the remote machine DNS for name resolution.

Then execute the notebooks to listen on external ports. For example, running 3 notebooks.

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080 --ip=0.0.0.0
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8081 --ip=0.0.0.0
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8082 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

You will use the Token on the output when running the notebooks for the authentication. It will display the output like this

```
http://server.example.com:8080/tree?token=dd9024f1fb68434645d3902d161f41720650644dc5832f16
```

Assuming the remote server is not blocking traffic to those port, then on you local machine it will be as simple as opening a browser to

```
http://<name-of-remote-machine>:8080/tree?token=<your-token>
http://<name-of-remote-machine>:8081/tree?token=<your-token>
http://<name-of-remote-machine>:8082/tree?token=<your-token>
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the jupyter notebook in the no browser mode with your custom port number

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888
```

Then setup up an ssh tunnel from the local machine:

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 <REMOTE_USER>@<REMOTE_HOST>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me. What worked, instead, is a slight variation of all the answers and is quite simple.

Open the notebook in the remote server as `jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=<remote-host-ip>`. Then copy the link from the remote terminal in the local browser, which is of the form `http://<remote-host-ip>:8888/tree?token=<>`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following on Windows, MacOS, and Linux Operating Systems, and all of them gave successful results!

### Windows Operating System

If you are using the Windows operating system, then make sure to have any client/terminal that can access SSH. I like the [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) as it is highly lightweight and very easy to use.

1. Open Git Bash
2. Connect to the remote computer/host using ssh

```bash
ssh remote_user@remote_ip
```

For example, suppose my remote user name is fahim and the remote IP is 103.101.50.2. Then the command would be:

```bash
ssh fahim@103.101.50.2
```

Write "Yes" when it asks to trust and add that connection.

3. Now, you need to use a port number that is not getting used by other applications or connections. For example, let's say, I am taking 8892 as my port number. I have already checked that port number 8892 is not getting used either on my local machine or the remote machine.
4. Now, I will open the Jupyter Notebook directly on my remote machine. As I have already been connected with the first git bash window, I can simply go there, and open my Jupyter notebook using:

```bash
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8892
```

5. Now, it is time to open the notebook on my local machine. As the first Git Bash window is connected with the remote machine and operating the notebook, I will open another Git Bash window.
6. In that new Git Bash window, I will catch the forwarded port using:

```bash
ssh -NfL localhost:8892:localhost:8892 fahim@103.101.50.2
```

Here,
"8892" is the port number that I chose earlier and it was not getting used by anything else at that moment.
"fahim" is the remote machine's username.
"103.101.50.2" is the remote machine's IP.
7. Now you can open any browser on your local machine. I prefer Chrome or Firefox, but you can use literally any web browser.
8. Go to `http://localhost:port_number`. As I used 8892 as the port number, I will go to `http://localhost:8892` to open the Jupyter Notebook on my browser.
9. Now I can enter the password if it has any. If it did not have any password pre-configured, then I can simply keep the password box empty and click continue.

After this point, I can use it without any hassle. But keep in mind to activate your conda environment if you have one before starting the jupyter notebook on your remote machine.

### Linux Operating System

All of the processes are the same. You can use any terminal as all of the terminals support ssh by default. As the process continues, use separate terminal window so that in one window you can see the ongoing process for the notebook, and in another window, you can catch the forwarded port.

### MacOS Operating System

All of the processes are the same. You can use any terminal as all of the terminals support ssh by default. As the process continues, use separate terminal window so that in one window you can see the ongoing process for the notebook, and in another window, you can catch the forwarded port.